# SQL - 1 index on 2 columns or multiple indexes

Tags: sql-server, performance, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

Consider a sql table Employer.

Column A -- (int) Unique identity column. Not used in select queries as part of the where clause.

Column B -- (int) Non unique column. Used in select queries as part of the where clause very often.

Which of the below choices of index are better for deigning the database table to achieve good performance with low maintenance

1) 1 clustered, unique, primary key on Column A and 1 non clustered index on column B

OR

2) 1 clustered, unique, primary key on Column B, A (Composite primary key)

OR

3) 1 non clustered, unique, primary key on Column A and 1 clustered index on column B

Any other suggestions are also welcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: Will Column A be used in `Where` clause. If yes then second index will not be helpful. Ordering is important in index with more than one columns.

Comment: What RDBMs?  I think some of the details will be vendor specific.

Comment: Column A will not be used as part of where clause

Comment: This  is for SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Go with option 1.
When creating primary key always aim at shortest possible column. Reason for it is that this column will be used in all other indexes. Also I hope when you say identity you don't mean randomly generated value, because it will hurt your performance for writing.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it is sequentially incremented.What about option 3? (edited some time back).

Comment: Usually the clustered index is made on ID column. And ideally on column, that is unique. When you will create another table let's say employee, then you will most likely refer to ID column in employer table. And because you have clustered index, you can quickly access all employer data for certain employee. Remember clustered index means that data are physically sorted according that column.

Answer (score 0):

Choose first , second will fill large space, because it is clustered and difficult to accompany, because it is composite. To choose first you will have small index and is easy  to accompany